# Tap on UITextField's clear button hides keyboard instead of clearing text

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard, uitextfield

In iPhone, I have a view which has a `UITextField`. When I tap on the clear button of `UITextField`'s the keyboard dismissed instead of clearing the text in the `UITextField`. On an iPad it is working correctly. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you post code how you are handling clear button?

Comment: Check to see if the clear button is blocked by another view, and thus, not receiving touch events.

Answer (score 48):

Just clear the field, `resignFirstResponder` (if you want to hide keyboard) and return `NO`/`false`

Note: set Attributes inspector property of `UITextField`

> **Clear Button -> Appears while editing**

so it will display the clear button while editing in the text field.

**// Objective-C**

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.text = @"";
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

**// Swift**

```
func textFieldShouldClear(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.text = ""
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this code after you attach delegate of uitextifield

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

First, check all the code blocks that related to your `UITextField` (especially the code `yourTextField.hidden = YES;`)

Put break points and analyze every `UITextField` delegates that you implemented.

(*`textFieldDidEndEditing`,`textFieldShouldEndEditing`,`textFieldShouldReturn.etc`.*)

OR

Implement the `textFieldShouldClear` delegate and write the code here to visible and clear your `UITextField`

To do this, you have to set the `clearButtonMode` as below,

```
yourTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
yourTextField.delegate = self;

//For active keyboard again
[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Then implement the `textFieldShouldClear` delegate

**YourClass.h**

```
    @interface className : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

**YourClass.m**

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
    yourTextField.hidden = NO;
    yourTextField.text = @"";
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: thanks for all your answers I got the problem where I'm making mistake.Now I'm done correctly

Answer (score 5):

Just make sure U've given these two

```
editingTextField.delegate = self;
editingTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

**TextFieldShouldClear** is needed only if you need to do some customizations :-)

Are you doing some thing in this method?

Maybe you are are calling resignFirstResponder in this delegate method, thats why the keyboard is getting dismissed.

Please go through the delegate methods, and check what u r doing exactly.

Answer (score 2):

This issue happened also if you have

```
yourTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
```

Check this line and delete it or change view mode..